# Xamarin.Forms 5 Tesseract Initialize false only on an iPhone device

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement this package in a Xamarin.Forms 5 app.

https://github.com/halkar/Tesseract.Xamarin

It works on the Android and iOs simulators but the only problem is I can't run it on an iPhone.
I get Initialized false and when I enable the usually suppressed exceptions i get "you have not allocated the native object";

These seem to be the exact lines that cause the error and I'm wondering what might be the reason:

The package: https://github.com/halkar/Tesseract.Xamarin/blob/f74d0cdb9b8de992582210f9d85afd918d1b3262/Tesseract.iOS/TesseractApi.cs#L43

Xamarin:
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/6225cac6694b54e09fc25ff9a23fad0308014125/src/Foundation/NSObject.iOS.cs#L32

Since simulators use a different architecture (arm vs x*) than the phones themselves could that be the problem?

Comment: Could you check this page:https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/10733.
It seems alike the same problem you had met.

Comment: Yes and I'm having the same problem: _I can't turn off Hot Restart either since i upgraded Visual Studio_ When you do turn it off, the Device disappears from debug targets.